# URL multiple redirection, hide redirection between source and destination redirection

Tags: url, redirect, hide

this is my question...

when I enter the browser url in

https://firsturl.com

it redirects to

https://secondurl.com

then also redirects to

https://thirdurl.com

and finally listed the content of url is

https://fourthurl.com

Here is my question, In between, the secondurl.com and thirdurl.com, not appeared both browser and user view.. we have to hide the between urls. not only 2 url, howmany url's listed in this between case, all the urls hide it. So, the customer only view sourceurl and destination url, which means, firsturl.com and fourthurl.com only appeared and view in browser and user perpective.

Could you please any one support or help me...
(Any kind of soltions like DNS, CName, .htaccess)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the main way redirection can be performed is either by including specific header (Location: http://url.tld) in the response, or by include some HTML code that automatically redirect the user to the destination path / url ().

- If there is sensitive data that is being transmitted in-URL during the redirection, then in this case all those request should be server-side (performed by the backend).
- If your just concerned about the UX and that there maybe some noticeable lag, then you should use the Location header.

Please provide more detail (what type of data is in the URL, why you don't wont the user to see the other urls) if you need a detailed answer.